# tkdiff blank error message while executing "font actual system"

Tags: linux, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am attempting to use the now venerable [tkdiff](http://sourceforge.net/p/tkdiff/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tkdiff) tool, but have run into a snag.  I have 2 Linux systems.  The first system, a Redhat EL 6.4 workstation, runs tkdiff perfectly fine--I can diff files all day long.

On a second system, a CentOS release 6.6 server, [tkdiff](http://sourceforge.net/p/tkdiff/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tkdiff) fails with the following stack trace:

```
Error in startup script: 
    while executing
"font actual system"
    invoked from within
"set sysfont [font actual system]"
    (file "<path...>/bin/tkdiff" line 122)
```

I don't know why it's not giving me an error message between the ":" and "while executing"...very strange.

I'm scratching my head on this one, I've tried a few things such as:

- replacing the `!#/bin/sh` shebang with `#!/usr/bin/wish`
- updating the `package require Tk` statement to 8.5
- Running wish, then sourcing tkdiff from inside wish: curiously, *this gives no errors!*  But it is not practical because it would be very cumbersome to specify the diff files and run this way.

I'm guessing I might be missing some other dependancy on my CentOS server?

**Update:**

Okay, it's definitely a dependency thing.  My brain is a little foggy on the details, but I recall there being some subtle differences when sourcing from the `wish` prompt vs just running a script, as far as error handling.  The root seems to probably be a missing font dependency, as this experiment shows:

```
$ wish
% font actual system
% puts $errorInfo

    while executing
"font actual system"
% puts $errorCode
NONE
%
```

Clearly it is not happy about `font actual system`.  Curiously, the `$errorCode` is `NONE`.  The libXft and fontconfig packages were previously installed.  And I just installed the following additional yum packages:

```
xorg-x11-utils
libXv
libXxf86dga
libdmx
tk-devel (which installed fontconfig-devel and a bunch of other dependancies)
tcl-devel
```

Comment: The fact that it works when sourcing tkdiff from within wish seems like a critical clue.  Something is different in the configuration when running from the shebang than running from a full environment.  However, I have no knowledge of CentOS or why it may be different.  Try looking to see where your TCLLIB environment variable is set in the various .login/.rc files and see if you get a clue.  Good luck!

Comment: Tk tries to have very few dependencies on other packages so that it is easier to build it and build on top of it. However, 8.5 does depend on fontconfig and Xft. Also, some languages' embedding of Tk is done in part with setting of environment variables, which can disrupt a normal Tk run. I don't know if any of this helps you…

Comment: Hmm, yum tells me my CentOS box has fontconfig.x86_64 and libXft.x86_64 installed.  I'll poke some more.

Comment: Solved!  Thanks to @DonalFellows and for providing the clues to narrow it down!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The system font on the X display server (local RHEL workstation) was not installed on the X-client where wish was running (CentOS server).

I think the problem was, at least in part, due to the fact that I was running the `tkdiff` program on the CentOS server and displaying via X to my original RedHat workstation.  I took the tcl stack trace of the root cause (`while executing "font actual system"`) and used that to narrow down the issue.  On the RedHat worstation, I launched wish and executed that command to get the following response:

```
RedHat>$ wish
% font actual system
-family {DejaVu Sans} -size 12 -weight normal -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0
%
```

I reasoned that the CentOS server, since it was displaying over X to my RHEL box, would be trying to use the same system font.  A quick search unconvered the proper yum package for this font, so I installed it.

```
sudo yum install dejavu-sans-mono-fonts
```

Voila!  On CentOS, I now get:

```
CentOS>$ wish
% font actual system
-family {DejaVu Sans Mono} -size 12 -weight normal -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0
%
```

The final test: `tkdiff` now runs fine!